# merge related records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this MySQL query:

```
select day(ReservationDate) as ReservationDay, sum(SleighSeats) as SleighSeats, sum(CabSeats) as CabSeats, 0 as IsFullMoon, '' as OverrideText
from Reservations
where month(ReservationDate) = 2
group by ReservationDate
union
select day(CalendarDate) as ReservationDay, 0 as SleighSeats, 0 as CabSeats, IsFullMoon, OverrideText
from CalendarOverrides
where month(CalendarDate) = 2
group by CalendarDate
order by ReservationDay
```

The Reservations table can contain any number of records for any given calendar date, or none at all. The CalendarOverrides table can contain exactly 1 or 0 records for each calendar date. I'm trying to merge the results together but not quite getting it right.

Here's my result set:

[image]

Reservation day 23 is the problem. I'd like those 2 records merged in 1 so that the 5 values are:
23, 6, 8, 1, [blank/null]

To clarify: 
- ReservationDay is in both tables (named CalendarDate in CalendarOverrides)
- SleighSeats and CabSeats exist only in the Reservations table
- IsFullMoon and OverrideText exist only in the CalendarOverrides table

The top query in the union will already merge all Reservations records on the same ReservationDay, but how can I merge any records in the bottom query with records in the top query, for the same ReservationDay? (So that there are never more than 1 record for any given day.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
    ReservationDay, 
    max(SleighSeats) as SleighSeats, 
    max(CabSeats) as CabSeats, 
    max(IsFullMoon) as IsFullMoon,
    max(OverrideText) as OverrideText
from (

    select 
        day(ReservationDate) as ReservationDay, 
        sum(SleighSeats) as SleighSeats, 
        sum(CabSeats) as CabSeats, 
        0 as IsFullMoon, 
        '' as OverrideText
    from Reservations
    where month(ReservationDate) = 2
    group by ReservationDate
    union
    select 
        day(CalendarDate) as ReservationDay, 
        0 as SleighSeats, 
        0 as CabSeats, 
        IsFullMoon, 
        OverrideText
    from CalendarOverrides
    where month(CalendarDate) = 2
    group by CalendarDate, IsFullMoon, OverrideText
) as subtbl 
group by ReservationDay
order by ReservationDay, IsFullMoon
```

Comment: You are 100% awesome! Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: This would only work because it is MySQL. Using an aggregate in the same select clause as a non-aggregate without a `GROUP BY` clause is non-deterministic and IMHO a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @lc. thanks for that. It was a quick answer from me and I wanted that SweatCoder would test and enhange the query. Anyway, I edited the query and latest version worked in SQL Server too, but perhaps your answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
select day(ReservationDate) as ReservationDay, sum(SleighSeats) as SleighSeats,
    sum(CabSeats) as CabSeats, COALESCE(IsFullMoon,0) as IsFullMoon,
    COALESCE(OverrideText,'') as OverrideText
from Reservations
left outer join CalendarOverrides 
    ON Reservations.ReservationDate = CalendarOverrides.CalendarDate
where month(ReservationDate) = 2
group by ReservationDate, IsFullMoon, OverrideText

union all

select day(CalendarDate) as ReservationDay, 0 as SleighSeats, 
    0 as CabSeats, IsFullMoon, 
    OverrideText
from CalendarOverrides
where month(CalendarDate) = 2
and NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Reservations 
    WHERE Reservations.ReservationDate = CalendarOverrides.CalendarDate
)

order by ReservationDay
```

---

If your RDBMS supports it, you should also be able to do this will a full join (this may be slower due to the `COALESCE` in the where clause?):

```
select day(COALESCE(ReservationDate, CalendarDate)) as ReservationDay,
    COALESCE(sum(SleighSeats),0) as SleighSeats,
    COALESCE(sum(CabSeats),0) as CabSeats, COALESCE(IsFullMoon,0) as IsFullMoon,
    COALESCE(OverrideText,'') as OverrideText
from Reservations
full join CalendarOverrides 
    ON Reservations.ReservationDate = CalendarOverrides.CalendarDate
where month(COALESCE(ReservationDate, CalendarDate)) = 2
group by ReservationDate, CalendarDate, IsFullMoon, OverrideText
order by ReservationDay
```

Comment: Thanks, though, for offering a solution. Preesh.

Comment: @SweatCoder Fair enough, changed the wording a little bit.